# Cosa vuol dire "tenere a porzione" in questo passaggio?

Tags: meaning

Nel romanzo *Mille anni che sto qui*, di Mariolina Venezia, ho letto (grassetto mio):

> Mentre Ciccillo il barbiere suonava la fisarmonica, fra una spasa di pasta e qualche costola di capretto, Aurelio aveva fatto del suo meglio per sventolare i suoi quarti di nobiltà, introducendoli delicatamente nel discorso.
>   Con finta indifferenza aveva nominato le sue terre, i Tre Confini, la Difesa, Rivolta Sant’Angelo, piú di duemila e settecento tomoli, guardandosi bene dal dire che la maggior parte erano incolte, intere distese di sterpaglie e di lumache, e le poche famiglie che ci **tenevano a porzione** facevano la fame.

La mia domanda è sul significato dell'espressione "tenere a porzione" che appare in questo brano. Sul [*Grande dizionario della lingua italiana*](http://www.gdli.it/JPG/GDLI13/01006.jpg) ho trovato che "a porzione" può significare

> in  proporzio­ne, secondo una proporzione determinata

ma questo non sembra avere molto senso nel passaggio sopra citato.

Immagino che il senso di "porzione" nel testo abbia a che vedere con [questa accezione](http://www.gdli.it/JPG/GDLI13/01005.jpg)

> Quantità  di  cibo  sufficiente  per  una  persona; razione  di  viveri  o  di  acqua  destinata  individual­mente  a  militari,  marinai,  ecc.;  cibo  che  serve  per
>   vivere

oppure con [questa altra](http://www.gdli.it/JPG/GDLI13/01006.jpg)

> – In  senso  generico:  stipendio;  pensione.  – Anche: compenso

ma non riesco a cogliere il senso di "tenere a porzione" nel contesto del testo. Me lo potreste spiegare?

Comment: Riporta per favore qualche linea del passo che precede la citazione. "Ci" è ambiguo fra pronome COD e avverbio di luogo.

Comment: @Nico: Fatto. Io credo che sia avverbio di luogo.

Comment: @charo hai ragione su "ci"=avverbio di luogo; secondo me il significato di stipendio che hai trovato è abbastanza corretto; quello che secondo me si avvicina di più, nelle pagine che hai linkato è "la quota dei frutti di un fondo spettante rispettivamente ai coloni (porzione colonica) e al proprietario o beneficiario (porzione dominicale)"; Aurelio di sicuro non lavora la terra in suo possesso, ma ci "tiene" delle persone che la lavorino per lui in cambio di una porzione dei frutti, comunque insufficiente e tale da patire la fame.

Comment: @RiccardoDeContardi Mi pare una buona interpretazione.

Comment: A senso si parla di mezzadria, ma non ho dei riferimenti puntuali.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

@charo è corretta l'interpretazione di *"ci"* come avverbio di luogo;

Per quanto riguarda il significato della frase, secondo me il significato di *stipendio* che hai trovato è abbastanza corretto.

Quello che secondo me si avvicina di più, nelle pagine che hai linkato è

> la quota dei frutti di un fondo spettante rispettivamente ai coloni (porzione colonica) e al proprietario o beneficiario (porzione dominicale)

Aurelio (il personaggio citato) di sicuro non lavora la terra in suo possesso, ma ci *"tiene"* (nel senso proprio di collocare, ospitare) delle persone che la lavorino per lui in cambio di una porzione dei frutti, comunque insufficiente e tale da far patire la fame.

*Tenere a porzione*

significherebbe quindi in pratica *far lavorare a porzione*, cioè solo per una parte dei guadagni o del raccolto.

Potrei sbagliarmi, ma non credo sia dissimile dal concetto di [fittavolo](https://it.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fittavolo)